# Couldn't create Workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I had problem with electricity, that reset my computer in developing mode. So this code, which **work** ***brilliant*** before:

```
InputStream fExcelTemp = new FileInputStream("XLStemplate/XLStemplate.xlsx");
//File fExcelTemp = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("XLStemplate/XLStemplate.xlsx"));

//This is evil!
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fExcelTemp);
//Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

- now give exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument
>       at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:72)

And this happen at the creating workbook step. I've looked several solution from [here](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-apache-xmlbeans-XmlException-td5501612.html) and [here](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025) and some others... I use "Invalidate cashes" and do another beautiful, *magic* and *non-understandable* solutions with adding libraries, set environments... But nothings work.

---

And now, I haven't any ***Idea*** (*Intellij*) what to do...

Comment: What is your classpath set to? Sounds like a library is missing. Perhaps when the power went out one of the libraries or your classpath got corrupt. Have you verified all the libraries? Try downloading again.

Comment: Why are you creating the workbook from a Stream when you have a File? The [docs are quite clear on you wanting to use a File if you can!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: Yep, I forgot to change my code. First it read from File, as it in comment line

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. After reset, it seems like the dependencies(?) were crashed. Now I have to include all libraries not from source like folder, but add to **each all of libraries themselves one by one**.

---

Thanks and sorry